# Why are all seders in the plural except for Moed?

Tags: talmud-gemara, mishna

Pretty straight forward question, but why are the Seders of the Mishnah in plural (zeraim, nashim, nezikin, kedoshim, tehorot) but Seder moed is not moadim?

Comment: Although I already answered. This question might be a duplicate. See: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28490/27180

Comment: @Shmuel thanks for the answer, and I didn’t see that post when I posted my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the website of the congregation of Bais Dov Yosef, it gives a bunch of possible answers. By: Rabbi A. Bartfeld as revised by Horav Shlomo Miller Shlit”a, see [there](https://baisdovyosef.com/511-what-is-wrong-with-seder-moed/):

> 1. It infers to the Yom Shekulo Tov or Olam Habba, which is but one day in the eyes of Hashem (ibid. Tamid 5b, Oraissa p.321)
> 2. The word Moed is actually already plural (Horav Chaim Kanievsky Shlit”a quoted in Chalichos Chaim 66 p.170, Introduction to Mishna
>    Mefureshes).
> 3. Even better, it hints that in the future all yomim tovim will become one single extended moed. Giving echo to the words of the Choze
>    of Lublin Zt’l, that in the days of Moshiach, Tisha Beav will become
>    the first day of yom tov, Shiva Asar Betamuz the last, while all the
>    intermediate days will be an extensive chol hamoed. (Tapuchei Chaim
>    ibid.)
> 4. It points to the yom tov of all yomim tovim, the Shabbos Shabboson or Yom Kippur (Bais Yaakov [Komarna] quoted in Pri Chaim p. 279).
>    Similarly, the masseches of Yom Kippur is Yuma (or Yoma) “the day”.
> 5. It is an allusion to the saying (Yalkut Mishlei 9, Yotzeir P. Zachor) that all yomim tovim will be annulled with the exception of
>    Purim. (Tapuchei Chaim p. 18, Noeh Doresh p. 103).